Is it smart to use RAII to manage files?
I wanted to create a class Channel that facilitates file writes in a special way. It was clear to me at first that I call open() on the file in the constructor and close() on the file descriptor in the destructor. But this would mean that I have to throw in the destructor if close() fails for some reason. Is it smart to use RAII for file management anyway? Should I throw in the destructor?
Live demo:
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h> /* open */
#include <unistd.h> /* close */
#include <stdexcept>
#include <filesystem>

class Channel
{
public:
    Channel(std::filesystem::path path_to_file)
    {
        _fd = open(path_to_file.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
        if (!_fd)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Failed to open file" };
        }
    }

    ~Channel()
    {
        int r = close(_fd);
        if (r < 0)
        {
            // ... ?
        }
    } 

private:
    int _fd;
};

int main()
{
    Channel("/home/user/myfile.txt");
}


Never throw in a destructor. If you want to detect errors on closing a file then close the file explicitly before it goes out of scope. I would still close in the destructor, just ignore any errors.

If close() fails, there's not really much anyone can do to handle that.  So instead of throwing an exception, just log an error message and continue (or if you think it's sufficiently serious to warrant it, you could terminate the program)

BTW, std::fstream("/home/user/myfile.txt"); is already close to what you need.

Don't forget rule of 5/3/0, i.e handle copy/move constructor/assignment (= delete; might be fine).

RAII has been the recommended C++ approach to open+close principle ever since the very beginning. But you need to aquire rule 350. Your  class is missing the copy constructor and copy assignment specifications. This opens the door for use-after-close and double-close problems.

Waay late here, but if (!_fd) is wrong, as open() returns -1 on failure, not 0: "RETURN VALUE Upon successful completion, these functions shall open the file and return a non-negative integer representing the file descriptor. Otherwise, these functions shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error. If -1 is returned, no files shall be created or modified."  N.B.: "return a non-negative integer representing the file descriptor."  0 is a valid return value.

It has been already mentioned in a comment. Compare to what the standard library does:
 { 
      std::ifstream f{"path/to/file"}; 
      f >> data;
      // f.close();  // possible but usually unnecessary
 }

The situation with std::ifstream is exactly what @john explains in their comment: The stream closes the file in its destructor. Any exceptions or errors encountered during that go unnoticed (because one should not throw from a destructor). If you want to check if closing the file succeeded you can call close explicitly (and that's about the only reason you want to call close explicitly).
Yes RAII is a good way to handle files. I remember Bjarne using that as example for why RAII is such a cool thing: It applies not only to memory, hence is more generally applicable compared to eg garbage collection.


Error Handling in Destructors
Throwing exceptions from a destructor is generally discouraged for a few reasons:

Unwinding Issues: If an exception is thrown while another exception is
already being propagated (e.g., during stack unwinding), the C++ runtime
will call std::terminate, leading to program termination.
Error Reporting: Destructors typically do not have a way to report errors
back to the caller. Throwing an exception doesn't provide a meaningful way
to handle the error since the context for handling it might no longer
exist.


Handling Errors in Destructors
Instead of throwing exceptions from destructors, consider these alternatives:

Logging: Log the error to a file or console to ensure that it's noticed by
the developer or user.
Error Code Storage: Store an error code in the class that can be checked
before the object is destroyed.
Explicit Close: Provide an explicit close() method that can be called
before the object goes out of scope, which can handle errors properly.




class Channel {
public:
    Channel(const std::string& filename) {
        file_.open(filename);
        if (!file_.is_open()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file");
        }
    }

    ~Channel() {
        if (file_.is_open()) {
            try {
                file_.close();
            } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e) {
                // Handle error without throwing an exception
                std::cerr << "Error closing file: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                // Alternatively, you can set an error flag or perform some other error handling
            }
        }
    }

    void write(const std::string& data) {
        if (!file_.is_open()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("File not open");
        }
        file_ << data;
        if (!file_) {
            throw std::ios_base::failure("Write operation failed");
        }
    }

    void close() {
        if (file_.is_open()) {
            file_.close();
            if (!file_) {
                throw std::ios_base::failure("Failed to close the file");
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::ofstream file_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        Channel ch("example.txt");
        ch.write("Hello, World!");
        ch.close();  // Explicitly closing to handle potential errors
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


